# Send button is sending data if there are error inside Edittext in Android

Tags: java, android, regex, button

i have used two edit text boxes where i have done validation for both the edittext boxes for email and confirm email address i have used text matcher and validation is working fine for me no issues when i checked it the data entered in the edittext is going inside database when i click the send button if there are error as well how to make the button disable when there will be error in any of the text boxes after correcting the error it has to deploy the data entered into database else it has to disable the button
i need to enter some thing to block the send button

I have done the validation here for edittext3 and edittext4 so if there any errors in this button has to disable where i must include

```
send.setEnabled(false);
send.setEnabled(true);
```

i must include this above method in this code

```
edittext3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            Is_Valid_Email_Address(edittext3);
        }

        public void Is_Valid_Email_Address(EditText edittext3) {
            if (edittext3.getText().toString() == null) {
                edittext3.setError("Invalid Email Address");
                valid_email = null;
            } else if (isEmailValid(edittext3.getText().toString()) == false) {
                edittext3.setError("Invalid Email Address");
                valid_email = null;
            } else if(edittext3.length() == 0 || edittext3.equals("") || edittext3 == null || "".equals(edittext3.getText().toString())) {
                valid_email = null;
            }else {
                valid_email = edittext3.getText().toString();
            }
        }
    });

    edittext4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {


        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            Is_Valid_Confirm_Address(edittext4);
        }


        public void Is_Valid_Confirm_Address(EditText edittext4) {
            if (edittext4.getText().toString() == null) {
                edittext4.setError("Invalid Email Address");
                valid_confirm = null;
            } else if (isEmailValid(edittext4.getText().toString()) == false) {
                edittext4.setError("Invalid Email Address");
                valid_confirm = null;
            } else if (edittext4.getText().toString().equals(edittext3.getText().toString())) {

                valid_confirm = edittext4.getText().toString();
            } else if(edittext4.length() == 0 || edittext4.equals("") || edittext4 == null || "".equals(edittext4.getText().toString())) {
                valid_confirm = null;
            } else {
                edittext4.setError("Confirm Email is Not Matching");
                valid_confirm = null;
            } 

        }
    });
```

//if there are any errors then button must become disable or enable to add it into database

```
    Button send= (Button)findViewById(R.id.send_email);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        String email = edittext3.getText().toString();
        String confirm = edittext4.getText().toString();


        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email_address",email));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("confirm_email_address",confirm));

            try
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.132/Android_App/Sendata.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

                Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "contact you shortly.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            try
            {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),SecondActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                }
                is.close();

                result=sb.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
               Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            }
            try
            {   
                    JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                    CharSequence w= (CharSequence) json_data.get("result");

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), w, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch(JSONException e)
            {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}

private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
}
```

does anyone know please help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        if(Is_Valid_Email_Address(edittext3.getText().toString())){
              send.setEnabled(true); 
        }else{
              send.setEnabled(false); 
        }
    }
```

Maybe try this? Apply it for edittext4 too.

Try this way.

Comment: i will get an error to change it to boolean @newbieee Is_Valid_Email_Address